# How to overwrite some data's in columnFicture?

Tags: testing, wiki, fixtures, fitnesse

my ColumnFicture test table look like this:

|categoryId|subcategoryId|showResults?|
|  2                 |                    1  |                               |

I overwrite in my ficture code (C#) categoryId (2) if subcategory is more than 0. Is that possible overwrite categoryId on fitnesse test site? That evry one can see what happend.

Answer (score 0):

No, from your fixture code you can not change the test in the FitNesse wiki. A test in the wiki is rendered into HTML, passed to a FitServer, parsed into a tree structure, passed to your fixture which can modify the tree, and then rendered into the test result HTML. So your fixture is too far down the pipeline to access the original wiki test source.